# Calculate fields between every two rows in database - grouped by entity - same table - postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Data in the view looks like this:

```
id      time                       revs       m_id  tag_id
320518  2017-04-05 14:01:25         216210396   1   1
320620  2017-04-05 14:11:33         216217766   1   1
27346   2017-12-09 15:15:52         699         2   1
27347   2017-12-09 15:19:52         1618        2   1
```

Goal: I need to calculate the revs per minute by doing the following:

`(row2 rev- row1 rev)/ (row2 time - row1 time)=revs per minute`
FOR EVERY two rows. Also FOR EACH m_id (1 and 2). in other words when the m_id changes - It will do the rows associated for that m_id. It also needs to be grouped by tag_id.

I need the result data to look like this:

```
time                 m_id    tag_id   time_diff     rev_diff   rpm
2017-04-05 14:11:33    1        1        10.13        7370      727.54
2017-12-09 15:15:52    2        1        4            919       229.75
```

There are thousands of rows. I've set the view to where it will order by m_id and then time.

The reason for keeping it all in the same table/ view is because I could have any number of m_ids. I need it to be dynamic so no matter how many m_ids are created - I can still determine the rpms.

My original solution was to create filtered views for each m_id but that won't work for a "drop-in" program.

UPDATE: 4/20/17

I've adjusted my script using @Tim Biegeleisen answer as a template (with my actual field names).

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        machine_id_id,
        rfid_tag_id,
        "event_at",
        LAG("event_at") OVER (ORDER BY "event_at" PARTITION BY machine_id_id) AS prev_time, 
rev_count, LAG(rev_count) OVER (ORDER BY "event_at" PARTITION BY machine_id_id) AS prev_revs
    FROM machines_status_updates
)
SELECT t.*,
       (rev_count - tprev_revs) /
       (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (t.event_at - t.prev_time)) / 60) AS rpm
FROM cte t
WHERE t.prev_time IS NOT NULL
```

It's still throwing a syntax error - at the first PARTITION BY - but I don't see a syntax error.

Error:

```
sql> WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        machine_id_id,
        rfid_tag_id,
        "event_at",
        LAG("event_at") OVER (ORDER BY "event_at" PARTITION BY machine_id_id) AS prev_time,
        rev_count,
        LAG(rev_count) OVER (ORDER BY "event_at" PARTITION BY machine_id_id) AS prev_revs
    FROM machines_status_updates
)
[2017-04-20 10:36:16] [42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "PARTITION"
[2017-04-20 10:36:16] Position: 154
```

Been through the documentation (as this CTE is a little new for me) - everything LOOKS right - I can't find what I'm missing.

For easier viewing:
[image]

EDIT (UPDATE on 4/52/2017) - Progress Made

Here's the newest version of the script (eliminating PARTITION Error and then Division by Zero error)

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        machine_id_id,
        rfid_tag_id,
        event_at,
        LAG(event_at) OVER (ORDER BY machine_id_id, event_at) AS prev_time,
        rev_count,
        LAG(rev_count) OVER (ORDER BY machine_id_id, event_at) AS prev_revs
    FROM machines_status_updates
)
SELECT t.*,
       (t.rev_count - t.prev_revs) / NULLIF(
       (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (t.event_at - t.event_at)) / 60), 0)  AS rpm
FROM cte t
WHERE t.prev_time IS NOT NULL;
```

Dataset looks like this: 
[image: Almost There...]

THE RPM is returning as NULL throughout the entire dataset - the rows all seem to be working well. Any ideas?

Final Answer:
WOOOHOOOO! Got it finally! :D  Worked from @Tim Biegeleisen's answer.

Final script:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        machine_id_id,
        rfid_tag_id,
        event_at,
        LAG(event_at) OVER (ORDER BY machine_id_id, event_at) AS prev_time,
        rev_count,
        LAG(rev_count) OVER (ORDER BY machine_id_id, event_at) AS prev_revs
    FROM machines_status_updates
)
SELECT t.*, (t.rev_count - t.prev_revs)AS rev_diff, (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (t.event_at - t.prev_time)
                                                     ) / 60) AS time_diff,
       (t.rev_count - t.prev_revs) / NULLIF(
       (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (t.event_at - t.prev_time)) / 60), 0)  AS rpm
FROM cte t
WHERE t.prev_time IS NOT NULL;
```

It was null because I was subtracting t.event from itself rather than prev_time. I added some columns so I could validate the rpms.

Final Result:

[image]

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question

Comment: @JohnConde - ok. sorry about that.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-window.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        m_id,
        tag_id,
        "time",
        LAG("time") OVER (ORDER BY "time" PARTITION BY m_id) AS prev_time,
        revs,
        LAG(revs) OVER (ORDER BY "time" PARTITION BY m_id) AS prev_revs
    FROM yourTable
)
SELECT t.*,
       (t.revs - t.prev_revs) /
       (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (t.time - t.prev_time)) / 60) AS rpm
FROM cte t
WHERE t.prev_time IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Got this error: `<operator>, <string>, <type>, AT, FOLLOWING, ISNULL, NOTNULL, OPERATOR, PRECEDING, TIME, WITH or '^' expected, got 'BY' ',', <query expression>, DELETE, INSERT or UPDATE expected, got '/'`

Researching now - but now sure why it's having an issue. It says it's just a syntax error.

Comment: @Nicoale I was missing an alias in the actual query.  It should be `SELECT ... FROM cte t`, with an alias `t`.

Comment: Perhaps `LAG()` cannot be used in a `WHERE` clause.  I updated my query to avoid doing this.  Now, the outer query just checks for `NULL` time diffs as indicator that this is the first record in the pair and should be dropped.

Comment: it's still throwing the same syntax error - it doesn't like this line ` LAG(time) OVER (ORDER BY time PARTITION BY m_id))) / 60 AS time_diff,` 
It's giving the same error I posted in the previous comment. @PavelHoral is kind of leaning in the direction I'm thinking - the version I'm using is Postgresql 9.6 - would the version have anything to do with the syntax error by chance? Looking into to it....

Comment: No, Pavel's link clearly shows that Postgres 9.6 supports `LAG()`.  Try escaping the time column in quotes as `"time"` in case time is a keyword.